# Create JSStringRef in Swift

Tags: swift, javascriptcore

I'm using the new (i.e., Objective-C) JavaScriptCore API in Swift. However, JSContext's evaluateScript method doesn't support the source URL and starting line number parameters that JSEvaluateScript (from the C API) does, so I'm trying to call the C method from my Swift code.

The C method takes JSStringRefs instead of Strings, so I need to create those. When I try the obvious solution:

```
println(JSStringCreateWithCFString("an example").takeRetainedValue())
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT). (I'm using `takeRetainedValue()` because the documentation notes that JSStringCreateWithCFString follows the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), but `takeUnretainedValue()` gives me the same error). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `JSStringRetain` and `JSStringRelease`?

Comment: @findall AFAIK those aren't available to Swift code. If you cmd+click a symbol like JSStringCreateWithCharacters, they're not in the generated list of symbols where they should be.

Comment: I've found the situation differs between Xcode 6.3 beta and 6.2. In 6.3 beta, the retain/release functions are visible in the list, and unfortunately even the return type of `JSStringCreateWithCFString` is different with 6.2.

Comment: Hmm… what's the return type in 6.3 beta?

Comment: `JSStringRef`, which is an alias of `COpaquePointer`.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried the simple example `let scriptJS = JSStringCreateWithCFString("window.foo = 'test'"); JSEvaluateScript(context.JSGlobalContextRef, scriptJS, nil, nil, 0, nil); JSStringRelease(scriptJS)` in Xcode 6.3 beta and it works fine. Do you think this is just a bug, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the Swift header for JavaScriptCore. The correct code would now be, for example:

```
import JavaScriptCore

let str = JSStringCreateWithCFString("an example")
let len = JSStringGetLength(str)
JSStringRelease(str)
```